# how to add a text box to django forms.MultipleChoiceField?

Tags: html, django, django-forms

when use "widget=forms.Select" there is text box automatically added, but when use "widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple" there are no text box around the choices. How to add the text box please?

```
in the forms.py

SEGMENTATION = (               
    (HIGH, 'High'),
    (MEDIUM, 'Medium'),        
    (LOW,'Low')
)
segmentation = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                            # widget=forms.Select,
                            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,  
                            choices=SEGMENTATION                                
                            )

in html

<div class="col-xs-5">
   {% bootstrap_field offer_form.segmentation %} 
</div>


[![now it looks like this][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbc6y.png
```

Comment: Maybe what you want is `widget=forms.SelectMultiple`?

Comment: @raphael  Thank you I will take your answer. The text box is added now, but the checkboxes are gone. That is okay.

Comment: Glad it’s working. I don’t think you *can* have *both* checkbox and text box at the same time.  Not sure if this is what you meant.